# Динамические контролы, кнопки, диалоги и т. д. в Android

Tags: android-sdk, android

Уже неделю мучаюсь, чтобы создать Activity или PreferenceActivity для одной цели - нужно реализовать окно, в котором есть кнопка добавить период (день недели, время с, время до), но сложность в том, что мы должно генерировать неизвестное количество периодов. То есть можем добавить их хоть 100.

Динамически добавить кнопки и поля в коде можно спокойно. Однако, допустим, проблема с кнопкой дни недели, которая вызывает AlertDialog с чекбоксами понедельник-воскресенье. Так вот проблема в том, чтобы при нажатии кнопки (которая появляется динамически с помощью кода) создавался под нее свой AlertDialog, так как алерт диалогу нужен конкретный constant id  для создания диалога.

[image: снимок]

Answer (score 1):

Хм.. перечитал вопрос 2 раза. Если суть проблемы сводиться к тому, что нужен id на строковой ресурс при создании AlertDialog, то есть одноименный метод, аргументом которого является CharSequence.

***[Справка Андроид]***

```
public AlertDialog.Builder setMessage (CharSequence message) 
Since: API Level 1 
Set the message to display.

Returns
This Builder object to allow for chaining of calls to set methods
```

Так что если текст должен быть всегда разный (генерируемый, допустим по результатам пересчета, а не строковые ресурсы заготовки), то можешь попробовать следующий код:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// Сообщение отображаемое в диалоге
//вместо этого метода
builder.setMessage(R.string.DayOfWeekSelect);
//использовать ЭТОТ
builder.setMessage("Select a day of week");
```